# Apache not loading htaccess but still rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just recently installed ubuntu on my home computer as a dual boot.

I have my htaccess in the following path:

```
/var/www/html/cortana/html/.htaccess
```

**I'm using the standard apache server version 2.4**

Now my Zend Framework project sits at:

```
/var/www/html/cortana/html/index.php
```

And we access it by going to `http://localhost/cortana/html/index.php` in the browser.

Here is my current `.htaccess`

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now when I go to `index.php` and type `<?php echo getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');die()?>` 
I get no response

Also, here is the error log:

```
[Thu Jan 21 03:00:06.542376 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 5262] [client 127.0.0.1:52981] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/cortana/html/.htaccess
```

**However it is actually using the mod rewrite module because its handling the redirects in the application. Also, if i completely remove the htaccess from the project html directory it still works**

I think it might be an apache configuration issue due to using a project inside the `/var/www/html` root path.

**Any help as to why its not using the supplied htaccess for the project would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: To do not put a website into a website. You will only struggle with possible configuration issues and effects of other .htaccess.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Can you provide an example on what to do?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I added the error log

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
allow from all
```

If it's still not working, please past the `.htaccess` file at the root of your project.

**EDIT:**

Or in your `virtualhost` configuration you might add `Require all granted`. Have a look at [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/418101/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration-despite-allowing-access-to-direc).